# Inserting html into a cytoscape node

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is there any way to insert html in a cytoscape node? (similar to foreign objects in D3)
I am trying to see if there is a way to build something like the image below with cytoscape. It will also have compund nodes, which is thereason I am looking at cytoscape.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create arbitrary content in a SVG document and use that as a `background-image` of the node.  That allows you to specify how nodes look programmatically.